# Is it possible to make more room in a graph layout for my VertexRenderingFunction?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Consider the graph produced by:

```
M = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
GraphPlot[M, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], LightRed, 
     Disk[#1, {.7, .1}], Black, Text[Subscript["C", #2], #1]} &)]
```

[image: Output]

Is it possible to tweak the layout so that more room is left around the vertices for use by the VertexRenderingFunction? (I want to be able to put more text in each of the labels.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally I'd recommend using `Graph` instead of `GraphPlot`. One way to solve your specific problem is to affect `VertexCoordinates` to scale your graph:

```
M = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
Manipulate[ AdjacencyGraph[M, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexShapeFunction -> 
({EdgeForm[Black], LightRed, Disk[#1, {.7, .1}], Black, 
Text[Subscript["C", #2], #1]} &),  VertexCoordinates -> scale   
AbsoluteOptions[AdjacencyGraph[M], VertexCoordinates][[2]]], {{scale, 2}, .1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: *Much* cleaner, thanks! I had to dig a bit to figure out what `scale` was multiplying, but it was worth it!

Comment: The arrows between nodes C2 and C4 are reversed ... is this a bug in the graph layout?

Answer (score 3):

How about changing the `AspectRatio`?

```
M = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};
GraphPlot[M, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], LightRed, 
     Disk[#1, {.4, .1}], Black, Text[Subscript["C", #2], #1]} &), 
 AspectRatio -> 0.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hmm, AspectRatio was the first option I tried, but my Mathematica (8.0.4 on Mac OS X) does not render it like you've shown here. Instead I just get a flatter version of the first diagram, with the ovals still overlapping.

Comment: yuck. The arrows coalesce to form a skewed 6pt star!

Answer (score 1):

This does the job in a rather brute-force manner:

```
stretch = {1.5, 1};
GraphPlot[M, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Line[Map[#*stretch &, #1]]} &), 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], LightRed, 
     Disk[#1*stretch, {.5, .1}], Black, 
     Text[Subscript["C", #2], #1*stretch]} &)]
```

[image: Output]

The downside is you have to do both edge and vertex rendering. I'll leave this question open, hoping someone has a better solution.